# Rails has_one through relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three tables: question, question_choices and response.

Question

- ID
- Name
- Tag

Question_Choice

- ID
- Question_id
- Label
- Value

Response

- ID
- User_id
- Question_id
- Value

Given a response, I want to see the question tag and the question_choice label for that.  Getting either response or choice to relate to question are no problem, but getting response to relate to choice is proving challenging because I need to say "value=value".  I have tried setting up a `:has_one, :through => :question` relationship but i'm not sure how to express the "value=value" stuff.  Do I just need to use raw sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't want to change the table structure (which would be the easiest solution). This is the solution for your current table structure:

**app/models/question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_choices
end
```

**app/models/question_choice.rb**

```
class QuestionChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**app/models/response.rb**

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :question_choice, :primary_key => 'value', :foreign_key => 'value', :conditions => proc { "question_id = #{self.question_id}" }
end
```

`Response.first.question_choice` will give you the `question_choice` of the first `response`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing questions have many question choices, and that responses have a single 'selected' question choice. To model this you would need a direct association between the response and question choice as well, e.g.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_choices
end

class QuestionChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :question_choice
end
```

This means that you would need to add a `question_choice_id` column to your `responses` table.